# RecyclerView hangs main thread with many elements

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` with an adapter that is based on a `List` of items. When I have ~400 elements in the adapter, I see the main thread hang for  about 1-2 seconds at the point when I notify the adapter that I've set new data.

I've method traced it and it's just busy deep in the view hierarchy (starts in `ViewRootImpl.performTraversal()`).  This doesn't make sense, as I'd expect it only to be rendering the 10-ish elements that are actually visible which should be lightning fast.

Am I missing some aspect of `RecyclerView`?

### Edit

It's calling `onBindViewHolder()` for every element in the list. This doesn't seem correct.

### Edit

If I give my RecyclerView a static height, it solves the problem. Not a solution in itself but hopefully points in a direction.

Comment: can you post some code e.g your whole adapter and from where you are calling adapter?

Comment: Yeah Thats does not seems correct .. You should post the Layout File and Adapter's Code with question ,,

Comment: Thanks @ADM and Faisal I linked the files.

Comment: I'm confused, why do you need a Handler in an Adapter/ViewHolder if all this happens on the main thread?

Comment: Because it allows any other UI events that were queued to be processed before the click handler is processed. Can you explain how you think that's related?

Comment: Is not necessarily related, nor needed (afaicr). You should only need to _post_ to the queue if you have a valid reason (e.g.: events that need to happen close to construction or measure/layout passes), where you want the message to be added at the end of the already busy main thread, but, I've never used it like this and i see no reason to introduce the coupling between an Android context/Handler and an Adapter. Seemed strange to me.

Comment: Post your layouts (the one that contains recycler's view and item view holder) if you can, maybe I can give you a better idea of why this is happening (as it's relatively common). :) Glad to hear you found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I still don't completely understand the root cause of this. When I set the height of the `RecyclerView` to something fixed (e.g. `"400dp"`) the problem resolved itself. Obviously though that isn't a proper solution but it got me started.

No arrangement of layouts I tried would solve the problem. I eventually converted everything to use `ConstraintLayout`, and after fiddling with layout widths and heights I found something that resolved the problem. It was related to using `"0dp"` for the height. Feels bad that I don't understand the root cause. I pasted the layout below in case it can help anyone.

Overall I am real lukewarm on `ConstraintLayout`. It's very verbose, and the constraint paradigm (vs. what I guess you'd call containment) doesn't feel natural. For example, needing to use the floating `Group` element to show and hide other logical groups, and using "chains" to center groups of elements.

The ironic thing is that everything was working fine with old school `LinearLayout`. I embarked on this as a learning exercise. You have to wonder what the real performance hit is for the average layout of using traditional `LinearLayout` + `ListView` vs. `ConstraintLayout` + `RecyclerView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:gravity="center">

  <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Large"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    />

  <android.support.constraint.Group
    android:id="@+id/content_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone"
    tools:visibility="visible"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="header,list_view"
    />

  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
    android:background="@color/gray_20"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/list_view"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    >

    <View
      android:id="@+id/device_image"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/device_name"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/device_name"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/name_label"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="2"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/device_image"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/device_model"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/device_model"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/model_label"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="2"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/device_name"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/device_id"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/device_id"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/id_label"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="2"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/device_model"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="@dimen/fadingEdgeLength"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:gravity="center">

  <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Large"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    />

  <android.support.constraint.Group
    android:id="@+id/content_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone"
    tools:visibility="visible"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="header,list_view"
    />

  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
    android:background="@color/gray_20"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/list_view"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    >

    <View
      android:id="@+id/device_image"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/device_name"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/device_name"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/name_label"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="2"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/device_image"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/device_model"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/device_model"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/model_label"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="2"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/device_name"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/device_id"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/device_id"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/id_label"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="2"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/device_model"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="@dimen/fadingEdgeLength"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: There are a few things you have to consider. 1st you can measure the performance between both, but CL+RV is not all about "only performance" when it comes to LL+LV. Neither of the later were designed with the required flexibility of more modern apps. LL Nesting+Weights is really expensive (it causes multiple layout passes/measures), something that is impossible in the limited time (16ms) you have per frame (to keep 60fps). The "fixed" height fixes your problem because you have a lifecycle problem, you're trying to do things when said things are not ready or said things simpley won't (1/n)

Comment: (2/n) ... do by themselves (e.g.: a ViewGroup not calling each children's draw method unless needed), etc. Said "optimizations" were put to try to reduce the number of times the views have to be measured, laid out, drawn, etc. I don't have the full use-case for what you're trying to do with this setup or why your architecture is making you struggle with this (I haven't seen it so I can't really help you much more in that area), but to understand why a fixed height is working and the other isn't, you have to dive deeper into how android measures and places your views in the screen at runtime...

Comment: (3/n). The whole process is a multi-stage/pass process. Views have to be measured first, they all views report their _fixed_ sizes, all the engine needs to do is one measure pass, one layout pass, and be done. The engine knows how much space there is, and the views are telling it how much space they need. Simple math. Now when you don't know the exact size (wrap content, 0dp, etc.), then the engine must resolve this value at runtime based upon various factors: total available space, and sum of all the spaces needed by each view...

Comment: (4/n) This can quickly become a chicken-and-egg problem. A view that WRAPS content, doesn't know how much space it needs, until it has the content available and measured (font size if there's text, margins, paddings, etc.). This can take more than 16ms and even much more than that. This is where Constraint Layout helps. Instead of relying on this "recursive" measure/layout process, it uses an algorithm (https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=504705) (same as iOS) to reduce the overhead and attempt to calculate said values in less passes...

Comment: (5/n) now, CL is fast and better for many things, but won't be out-of-the-box faster than a simple LL or simple layouts with fixed sizes, but I don't have numbers for this (although CL authors have mentioned this many times). However, in your case, chances are, due to how things work, there's simply someone *not* correctly calculating the height of certain items; height in vertical lists is very important, for it also drives part of what RV needs to do its job (recycle views). In any case, this is not the right place to go any deeper into why a fixed height changes everything.

Comment: (6/n) so.. my suggestion to you is to try to find out why, because it will help your life as an Android developer much easier. CL may be more verbose, but that's because you're telling the engine how you'd like each thing to react in relation to others, and not simply having "isolated" (viewGroups) rules inside these groups (RelativeLayout, Linear, etc.) that must be individually calculated and that *may alter the already calculated values* for other viewGroups. (starting the process again). Think about how long this takes + how long it takes to init a RV/LV, adapters, etc.

Comment: (7/7) at the end of the day, if the engine is unable to calculate things on time, you get this weird behavior where a view ends up having 0 height, and what not. Without access to your entire project, it's very hard to simulate this. If you one day publish a small sample showing each behavior, perhaps you can view what is happening in isolation and by just trying to reproduce this in your sample project, you also gain the necessary knowledge to better understand what is going on. (Happens to me all the time). Glad to hear you fixed it. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think it'd be useful if you could post this as answer. I think the problem is first, I shouldn't be able to make something that has this sort of performance problem. It shouldn't be allowed from use of a high-level API. How many people are using RecyclerView and have the same problem but don't realize because the number of elements is small? Second, there's really no good explanation out there how to avoid this problem.

Comment: Will do. And will add answers to your two (valid) questions. Keep in mind some of these are my opinions based upon my limited experience (like all experience, it's not all about the number of years, but also how broad/deep your Android knowledge is in particular areas of interest). I happen to have worked a lot with custom views and had to learn how a LayoutManager works to create a custom one so there's that... in any case, take everything with a grain of salt :)

Comment: Bad news... I had written a lot and... mistakenly lost it. I'll write in an external editor and paste it back here. Not today, maybe on Monday if that's ok. Thanks.

Comment: Coming back and reading this later.. "The "fixed" height fixes your problem because you have a lifecycle problem"... what? A view has no lifecycle, and I'm just populating the adapter in #onStart.

Comment: View do have a lifecycle; the fact that is different from a Fragment, that, in turn, is also different from an Activity, is on Google. Views are attached and detached, layouts need to be inflated, and measured, and then laid out. All this "magic" takes time. A fixed height, is a HUGE shortcut in the process (basically, the view measuring becomes trivial, it's hardcoded and therefore, fast). When the view must be measured (wrap for example) things take _way longer_ (now you need to measure everything that affects this view... this takes more time, and thus the lifecycle is now involved).

Comment: If by lifecycle, you mean the internal implementation details of RecyclerView then I agree. You said: "you (meaning me) have a lifecycle problem". As a consumer of the public interface, all I do is inflate it and set an adapter. If I have to care about the implementation then something is wrong that is out of my control.

Answer (score 2):

I see a few issues and I'll point them out in no particular order; although I haven't seen anything specific yet that may be causing your issue, as I write this answer, I may discover a few things, so let's analyze your code.

#### What's missing?

You didn't include more code, so I have no clue how you use this adapter, or how does your recyclerview layout is (is it contained inside another scroll view or nested scroll view?)
These are important questions because it may affect how the Android rendering/layout engine is working.

### The Layout

You're using a LinearLayout (kinda not needed here) with weights. These are not recommended unless you have a very valid reason; calculating the widget's sizes and what not, is expensive, and more so when there are images and bitmaps involved.

I recommend you switch to a ConstraintLayout and *do the right thing*. You will thank yourself and your layout will likely perform better (nothing in your current layout is impossible for ConstraintLayout, from what I see).

#### The Adapter

- This is strange:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      Listener l;
      if ((l = listener) != null) {
        mainHandler.post(() -> l.onItemClick(devices.get(getAdapterPosition())));
      }
    }
```

A click should always happen on the Main Thread, you don't need to post anything.
I'd write that as:

```
if (listener instanceof Listener) { //already fails if L is null anyway) 
     listener.onItemClick(...)
}
```

- In your `onBind` you perform a lot of lookups, you can save cycles if you cache these. E.g.:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(SetupAppUtils.getDeviceImageUrl(context, device)).into(image);
```

I have no clue what your `SsetupAppUtils.getDeviceImageUrl` method does, but it could be expensive, and you could save that locally in a Map if needed (lookup the URL once, reuse) (just an idea, impossible to tell without looking at the code)

- You seem to have a lot of business logic embedded in your onBind method (lots of `if` statements, is usually a red-flag. Your adapter couldn't care less about this, it's just "adapting" the data from model -> view and should not make decisions and perform transformations if it can be avoided. In this case, I see you pass a `Device`... seems ok but you appear to be doing a lot of checks and transformations, remember this is going to happen for all your items once they are being bound..., every time the user scrolls and a new item needs to be bound, you perform all this work again, when all you want is to "rebind" the viewholder.
- You're notifying a full change, which means a LOT for a recyclerview (all has to be re-measured and laid out again) because you're essentially telling the adapter: all the data has changed.

```
  void setDevices(List<Device> devices) {
    this.devices.clear();
    this.devices.addAll(devices);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
```

It's very straightforwards to use a [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil) (included with the framework!) and totally recommended.

- You override a method, but all the items have the same id:

```
  @Override
  public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
  }
```

If you cannot provide a good Id, then don't override this. I'd return item[i].something() (check for null/empty lists before!). Also rename `i` to `position` because that's what it is.

#### Anything Else?

Ouside of these, I don't see anything super strange. I'd make a simple test: remove all the binding code you have there (all the code in onBind) and just put `name.SetText(...)` and see if you still see the "lag".
If you don't, then you know some of these operations are taking longer than others.

Try with less items, see what happens; a recyclerview should be binding only the views that are visible +/- a few up/down, not 400 items at once. 
The only reason I can think of, is if your RecyclerView is inside a NestedScrollView or similar.

Comment: (also, If your lag is when you do notifyDataSetChanged, then don't do that, use a DiffUtil, it will save you a lot of headaches, you even have an async version)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: 1. Picasso has caching built in. 2. I converted to a constraint layout and that make no difference. 3. Removing getItemId() had no effect.

Comment: Did you try diff util?

Answer (score -1):

400 items to be loaded once is too much , you should use **Pagination** mechanism .Google now introduce [paging library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging) as part of android Jetpack. Plus you will find plenty of article and tutorials  discussing how it could be implemented in android.

Comment: I don't think so. As I understand it, that's about paging out the loading of the data. I've already loaded all of the data. That's happening async and isn't the problem. The point of recycler view is that it can intelligently render only the visible elements (plus some padding). If it can't do that, what's the point? I'll just render them in a linear layout and a scroll view.

Comment: 400 items is NOT a lot of items to be loaded at once; not for a recycler view (obviously if each item is 400 mb in size that may be a problem) but I've preloaded recycler views with thousands of items and never faced any issue (aside from well.. the memory for the objects).